# ExpressJs Function Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I'm following an Elasticsearch and ExpressJS tutorial I found online to interact with ES via an ExpressJS API. Whenever I go run a search for something from the index via Postman I get this error:

`"TypeError: elasticClient.suggest is not a function at Object.getSuggestions (/node-app/search-api/elasticsearch.js:11:26)`

The function is being exported and has the correct closing {} & (). Am I missing something that would cause that error? Any tips would be greatly appreciated

**elasticsearch.js**

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

const elasticClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'info'
});

var indexName = 'products';

function getSuggestions(input) {
    return elasticClient.suggest({
        index: indexName,
        type: 'product',
        body: {
            docsuggest: {
                text: input,
                completion: {
                    field: 'suggest',
                    fuzzy: true
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
exports.getSuggestions = getSuggestions;
```

**route.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var elastic = require('../elasticsearch');

router.get('/suggest/:input', function (req, res, next) {
    elastic.getSuggestions(req.params.input).then(function (result) {
        res.json(result)
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Update**
Looks like the method doesn't exist as Jaromanda mentioned. Looking through the API docs to put together what I need: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-search

Comment: it would appear that instances of `elasticsearch.Client` do not have a method called `suggest` - perhaps `elasticClient.suggest` should be `elasticClient.search` ?

Comment: Incredibly helpful! I'm still trying to navigate APIs and docs and you pointed me exactly where I needed to be. The tutorial was based on ES4 so I'm sure between 4 and 6 there have been significant changes.

Comment: what version of elasticesearch are you using?

Comment: @Bamieh ElasticSearch 6.0